# unexcept import in Node runtime

Tags: node.js, babeljs

[image]

When I use babel-node, it give me some error, the code below.

[image]

Comment: *the code below* - which file is it? And why are you using babel-node together with @babel/register? It's either one or another.

Comment: this file is an entry of Vue SSR's server file, babel-node and @babel/register cannot use together?

Comment: They *shouldn't* be used together because they serve a similar purpose but @babel/register has certain limitations. Use Babel config file with babel-node.

Comment: "(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import _Pro
mise from "../../core-js/promise";
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import"

it still give this

Comment: Please, update the question with your current Babel config. This likely means that the config isn't applied, so modules aren't transformed to `require` like it's expected for Node.

Comment: in the project dir, the content is "
  module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@babel/preset-env',
    '@vue/app'
  ],
  plugins: ['syntax-dynamic-import', 'dynamic-import-node'],
}
" of babel.config.js